# How to calculate the memory usage of a deep LSTM network?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, lstm, gpu, deep-learning

I was trying to estimate the memory usage for my LSTM network by referring to an examples of CNN memory usage calculation at http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#computational-considerations . The LSTM network architecture is as follows:[image]

My input data is of dimension (None,4,34569) float 32 values and With batchsize=8, the following are my estimations of memory usage

**Parameters:** 482646529*(4/2^20)***3**=5.4GB

Given as No_of_parameters *memory_per_float32*factor.

The factor of 3 is to consider the  memory to hold parameters, gradients in BP and optimization cache(if adam, RMSprop etc are used).

**Activations:** No_of_activations*(4/2^20)x**2** =129857*(4/2^20)*2 =1MB

The factor of 2 since the memory must hold the activations for backward pass

Here the No_of_activations are calculated as follows:

*lstm_1*: 6*4*3072=73728

(used '6' because of forget,input,output gate, cell state, cell candidate,output activation and '4' for the length of time sequence)

*dropout_1*: 4*3072=12288

*lstm_2*: 6*4*1024=24576

*dropout_2*: 4*1024=4096

*lstm_3*: 6*4*512=12288

*dropout_3*: 4*512=2048

*time_distributed_Dense_1*: 256

*dropout_4* :256

*time_distributed_Dense_2* : 128

*dropout_5*: 128

*time_distributed_Dense_3*: 64

*time_distributed_Dense_4*: 1

Total number of activations: 129857

**Miscellaneous** : 4*34569*(4/2^20)=0.52MB

**Total Memory** :parameters_memory+activations * batchsize+Miscellaneous * batchsize = 5.4GB + 1MB *8 +0.52MB *8 **~=5.4GB**

I am not sure if the no of activations required has been calculated correctly. Also Please let me know if the above memory calculations are appropriate. I am trying to train this network on 12GB GPU but I am running out of resource in the first epoch. If the above estimates are not appropriate, then could you please hint me towards a way to find roughly the memory usage for an LSTM network?

Comment: did you end up figuring this out?